# Javascript form submission when pressing enter not working in Firefox with saved password

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a simple login form that captures username/password with some simple Javascript (JQuery) to submit the form when the user presses enter in either of those fields. Here's the relevant bits of code:

The form:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    etc...
</form>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#username, #password').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#loginForm').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is specific to **Firefox** when the user has turned on the feature to have the browser save their passwords.

If I type the first few letters of my username in the username text field Firefox will present me with the options that it has remembered. If I press the down arrow to highlight the username and then hit the enter key to select it then my Javascript is firing **before** Firefox auto-completes the password field. This results in a blank password being submitted.

It works fine when using the same 'save passwords' feature in Chrome.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: Have you checked the focus ? Was it on password or username input or the submit button (if you have added) ?

Comment: Focus is on the username field because that's where I was typing. I type the first few letters of the username, then select the first option that Firefox presents in it's list of saved username/passwords. When I hit enter to select the first option the Javascript is firing and submitting the form, before Firefox can fill in the password field.

Comment: Why do you need to do bind that event listener at all?  Normally an enter keypress in a password field will just submit the form...

Comment: Boris, some browsers can be picky about that, and you typically need a submit button for it to work (my form has a link to submit the form which has been styled as a button with an image). Also, I wanted the form to submit if the user hits enter in the username field too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed keypress to keyup and all it works perfectly.

```
$('#username, #password').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#loginForm').submit();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Thanks **CoolEsh** for the tip